# free() function causes crash after several memmove's

Tags: c, arrays, free, memmove

I am writing a function acting like the`splice` function in js:given an array (of any type), delete some element starting at a given index, and stuff some new element in the gap (expand or shirnk the original array if needed).

I am using MinGw/Eclipse CDT under Windows7. Here is my code:

```
void* splice(int typesize,void* arr,
        int size,int start, int length,
            void* stuff,int size2){
    //length is the number of elements to remove
    //and size2 is the number of elements to fill in the gap

    //so size-gap will be the size of the new array after the function
    //when gap is a minus number, the array grows
    //and when gap is a positive number, the array shrinks
    int gap = length-size2;
    void* ptr = malloc(typesize*(size-gap));//--------(1)--------
    if(ptr==NULL){
        puts("error");
        return NULL;
    }
    //now the ptr array is empty, copy the original array(arr)
    //to the ptr until the 'start' index
    memmove(ptr,arr,typesize*start);

    //fill the new array 'stuff' into ptr starting from 
    //the index after 'start'
    memmove(ptr+typesize*start,stuff,typesize*size2);

    //and copy the rest of the original array (starting from 
    //the index start+length, which means starting from 'start' index
    //and skip 'length' elements) into ptr
    memmove(ptr+typesize*(start+size2),arr+typesize*(start+length),
            typesize*(size-start-length));

    return ptr;
}
```

and I also write some test code, the snippet below is for `long long` type:

```
int main(){
    setbuf(stdout,NULL);
    int start = 1;
    int delete = 6;
    long long* oldArray= malloc(sizeof(long long)*7);
    long long* stuff = malloc(sizeof(long long)*3);
    oldArray[0]=7LL;
    oldArray[1]=8LL;
    oldArray[2]=4LL;
    oldArray[3]=1LL;
    oldArray[4]=55LL;
    oldArray[5]=67LL;
    oldArray[6]=71LL;
    stuff[0]=111LL;
    stuff[1]=233LL;
    stuff[2]=377LL;
    int newsize = 7-(delete-3);
    void* newArray = splice(sizeof(long long),oldArray,7,start,delete,stuff,3);
    if(newArray){

        //------------crash happens here-----------
        //free(oldArray);
        //-------------

        oldArray =  newArray;
        int i=0;
        for(;i<newsize;i++){
            printf("%I64d\n",oldArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It should output 7, 111,233 and 377 (delete six elements from index 1 and stuff 111,233 and 377 into the array).

I tested for char, int, and long type arrays and under all situations the code worked. Except for one problem:I cannot free the old array. It seemes that the memory block cannot be reclaimed once it has been accessed several times by `memmove`.

If I change malloc to realloc at (1) and the free() won't crash, but I can no longer make the function work right (And I am not sure whether the free() function really worked or not).

Please give some advices about how this problem arise and how can I improve my code.

Comment: If you can't free that block it basically says it's damaged so you go beyond array boundaries somewhere

Comment: Does this specific example cause a crash for you? Because it works fine for me and I can't see anything wrong. If it does crash try commenting out the `memove()` one at a time to see which one (if any) is causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line:

```
    memmove(ptr,arr,typesize*size);
```

It tries to move typesize * size bytes to ptr. But you only allocated typesize*(size - gap) bytes. That will lead to a crash if gap > 0 unless you are very unlucky.

I stopped checking after the first bug I found, so there may be more, and I didn't bother finding out what the code does. You should add a comment which describes what the function should do well enough so that I could implement it without guessing or asking you questions.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my post. In fact the gap can be a minus number.The function is aimed to modify a array:delete some element starting from a index, and fill the element of another array into the gap. The original array is expanded or shrinked depending on how many elements are removed and how many new elements are stuffed in.

Comment: Thank you,now the program works well. The problem does stem from the bug you found.